# Given a String s and a 'word' String, return a copy of s where all of the characters have been replaced with a + except occurrences of the word

Tags: java, for-loop

This is the promblem I am trying to solve

> Given a String s and a 'word' String, return a copy of s where all of the characters have been replaced with a + except occurrences of the word

```
Ex: problem5("12xy34", "xy")        -> "++xy++"
Ex: problme5("12xy34xyabcxy", "xy") -> "++xy++xy+++xy"
```

This is the code I have so far.  However, it is incorrect.  I don't understand how it does not work.  I started by assigning a new string to "".  Then by using a standard for loop that compares if the word is at the given place in the S string.

```
public static String problem5(String s, String word) {
    String newString = "";
    for (int i=0; i <= (s.length()-word.length()); i++) {
        if (s.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word) == false) {
            newString += "+";
        }
        else 
            newString += s.substring(i, i+2);
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Any tips or advice about what I did wrong would be much appreciated.  I am trying to learn so a basic explanation of what I did wrong would be amazing.  Thanks to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your code:

1. You hardcoded the length of `word`:

   ```java
   else 
       newString += s.substring(i,i+2);
   ```

   should be:

   ```java
   else {
       newString += s.substring(i, i + word.length());
   }
   ```

   which of course is the same as:

   ```java
   else {
       newString += word;
   }
   ```
2. You don't skip the word after copying it:

   ```java
   else {
       newString += word;
       i += word.length() - 1; // skip word (-1 since loop does i++)
   }
   ```
3. Loop ends early, so you're missing the remaining `+`:

   ```java
   while (newString.length() < s.length()) {
       newString += "+";
   }
   ```

All in all:

```java
public static String problem5(String s, String word) {
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length() - word.length(); i++) {
        if (s.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word) == false) {
            newString += "+";
        } else {
            newString += s.substring(i, i + word.length());
            i += word.length() - 1;
        }
    }
    while (newString.length() < s.length()) {
        newString += "+";
    }
    return newString;
}
```

A very similar solution, using `StringBuilder` and `startsWith()`:

```java
public static String problem5(String s, String word) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.substring(i).startsWith(word)) {
            buf.append(word);
            i += word.length() - 1;
        } else {
            buf.append('+');
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Because goal are good to have, in Java 9+ it can be done simpler using regex:

```java
public static String problem5(String s, String word) {
    return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(word) + "|(?s:.)").matcher(s)
            .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().equals(word) ? word : "+");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, debug it. Find a suitable input string as a test (so, one where your program returns the wrong result) and turn yourself into the computer: Take out pen and paper if you have to, but follow along and calculate every step by hand. Then, use a debugger or if you can't be bothered to learn how to use one, add a bunch of `System.out.println` statements, and at every step, check what you got with what the computer got.

Every time you find a discrepancy, voila. You found a bug, and usually it's fairly obvious what you got wrong.

For example, here if you are at the `x` in your input string, you correctly conclude that you've got  `xy` in your input, and thus you print.. well, you print a 2-length string, which is already wrong, because `word` may not be exactly 2 characters long, but it works for `xy`. Which shows why it is important to try a bunch of different inputs before you should conclude your algorithm works properly. But that's not the only problem: Then you just advance `i` by one, so next your algorithm checks the `y`, and prints a + which is wrong - you've already covered that y.

We're still not done: Your algorithm then stops 2 chars before the very end because `xy` can no longer occur. Fair enough, but you just stop there, whereas the question requires that you still print some +s, and you don't. I don't think it's wise if your programming career involves you just trying something, failing, giving up, and hoping SO helps you out. Then 'SO question asker' would be a more appropriate job description.

Thus, your real problem is that you need to learn debug skills :) - us weathered programmers... also do that. At least, I do. Hopefully you can use my advice on how to do that for this one and for the rest of your programming career. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option to handle this using string splitting:

```java
String s = "xy12xy34xyabcxy";
String word = "xy";
String output = Arrays.stream(s.split(word, -1))
    .map(x -> x.replaceAll(".", "+"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(word)); 
System.out.println(output);   // prints xy++xy++xy+++xy
```

This approach here is to first split the input string on the word (`xy` in the example above).  Then, we place each character in the array by `+`, then join the parts again using the word as the separator.  Note that we use the `-1` option as the second parameter to `String#split`, to cover the edge case where the input might end in the word.  In this case, we want to ensure that the split would generate an empty array element on the RHS of the array.